# Account - Display fields on the Object's layout based on particular values

Tags: trigger, force.com, page-layout

I need to show particular fields based on the value of the fields. Does it sound weird? Below an example:

**First Account record:

- Type: Customer
- IsPartner: false

**Second Account record:

- Type: Business partner
- IsPartner: true

I do not want people to see the field IsPartner if the entry's Type is set to customer.

I am looking for a solution without creating any Visualforce page.

Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Can Type be a RecordType?

Comment: Can you create different account recordtypes and hide/show fields based on that in layout?

Comment: I have never heard about record type. Can this accomplish the requirement? If yes, I do not mind to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create record types for these different options. With record types you will be able to assign specific page layouts to each of your record types and select which fields should appear on the depending on which option is chosen. The following links should help you get started with creating some record types.

[Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm)

[View and Edit Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=viewing_and_editing_record_types.htm&language=en_US)

[Create Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_record_types.htm&language=en_US)

[Considerations for Creating and Updating Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there any way the record type can be changed by interacting with the layout of the entries?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here? When you say entries, are you referring to creating or importing new records?

Comment: Hi,
I wanted to know if there is a way of changing the record type by using the interface. I have just seen that it is possible to add the record type on the layouts so the end-users can change the record type any time.

Thank you!!

Comment: Your welcome! Also, Welcome to the community!